# Need To Use Sed To Change The "Nth" Character Of Pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I'm having difficulty piecing together the sed syntax to change the last numeric character of this string: `<FITID>1261703816`
I have a file with several of those fields that need changed but the numeric portion of the string will always be different.  However, the amount of numeric characters will always be the same (10). Basically I just need to change the last character of: `<FITID>1261703816` to something like: `<FITID>1261703817` on a file that contains several hundred of those fields.

Comment: If `sed 's/.$/7/'` doesn't do what you want then [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and provide more realistic and truly representative sample input/output.

Answer (score 1):

This command will change the tenth digit after `<FITID>` to `7`:

```
sed -E 's/([<]FITID[>][[:digit:]]{9})[[:digit:]]/\17/g' file
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
words, words, <FITID>1261703816 and more words
$ sed -E 's/([<]FITID[>][[:digit:]]{9})[[:digit:]]/\17/g' file
words, words, <FITID>1261703817 and more words
```

This requires just a single substitute command.  `[<]FITID[>]` matches `<FITID>` where we put the angle brackets into square brackets because some seds would otherwise treat them as special.  `[[:digit:]]{9}` matches nine digits.  We use `[:digit:]` in place of `0-9` because it is unicode-safe.  These characters are all put in parents, `(...)`, so that, in the replacement text, we can reference them as group `\1`.

Comment: That'll work on a Mac or BSD system; if you have GNU `sed`, you need `-r` instead of `-E`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler GNU sed supports `-E` too (shh - it's a secret!).

Comment: @EdMorton: Yup; you're right — it's not something that `sed --help` advertizes.  Pity; it means there's a simple way of making the job work more places without all the fuss.

Comment: Yeah, I can't imagine why they haven't documented it and it makes so much sense for `-E` to mean `Extended Regexps` in sed just like it does in `grep`. Naming it `-r` was goofy - they're maybe just embarrassed :-).

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much as this worked!  I was way off target, first I was using [0-9] instead of [:digit:] (I was unaware I could even do that).  I was also using sed -r and did not include any brackets with <FITID>.  Using the regex with sed is just not clicking with me yet, I guess it just takes practice, practice, practice.  Thanks again!

Comment: One more thing, is it possible to include this command in the replace portion of sed: `tr -c -d 0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c 10` so it would look something like this: `sed -E 's/[<]FITID[>][[:digit:]]+/<FITID>"$(tr -c -d 0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c 10)"/g'`?  I wanted to basically generate a random 10 digit number EACH time sed found a pattern match and apply that to the end of <FITID>.  Storing that command as a variable does not generate a new 10 digit number each time.